# how to check old backup (SQL SERVER) on blob storage. I want to check whether last one year backup files present in Container or not

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi All I want to check last one year backup files on container how can i do it? checking manually is tedious can any one suggest. I search a lot but i find how to delete these old backup files using power shell script. can anyone suggest??

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

For example, to a single blob, you can do like below to get the year of your backup blob create time:

```
        String str = "https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/test/interview2.txt";
        Uri uri = new Uri(str);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri);
        blob.FetchAttributes();
        DateTime blobtime = blob.Properties.Created.Value.UtcDateTime;
        String year = blobtime.Year.ToString();
        int year2 = Int32.Parse(blobtime.Year.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + "\n" + blobtime + "\n" + year + "\n" + year2);
```

Above code is how to get create year of your single backup file, and Mutiple blob in container is similar. Let me know whether this answered your question.:)